# Не возвращает return

Tags: javascript, node.js

Не могу понять, почему если через console.log, то вижу данные, а если через return то ничего не приходит. Помогите разобраться.

```
function ItemsPriceList() {
request(`http://api.csgo.steamlytics.xyz/v1/items/popular?key=14a71e5341037ffa4ea94067189e9db7`, (error, response, body) => {
return body
})
}
ItemsPriceList()
```

Comment: Так в коде нет команды вывода результат а куда-нибудь

Comment: @Дмытрык надо вывести в переменную?

Comment: Как можно возвратить `return`??? `return return`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае,`return` возвращает значение *из коллбэка, передаваемого параметром в функцию `request`*, а вовсе не из функции `ItemsPriceList`.
Сама функция `ItemsPriceList` возвращает `undefined` просто потому, что в ней оператор `return` не используется.

Так как обратный вызов в `request` выполняется асинхронно - возвращать `body` необходимо так же асинхронно: либо передавая параметром во внешнюю callback-функцию, либо возвращая из `ItemsPriceList()` экземпляр Promise (с передачей `body` параметром в `resolve`).

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция корректно возвращает body, вы просто ничего с ним не делаете.
Также, не совсем понятно, в каком формате вы хотите получить эти данные. 
Отобразить на html странице или обработать их в будущем, например, специфичный поиск и последующий вывод? 
Если банально вывести на экран, то посмотрите эти output js команды https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Comment: Я хочу обработать их в будущем.

Comment: Тогда используйте переменную. var dataFromBody=ItemsPriceList(); и передайте ее в необходимую в будущем вам функцию.

Comment: это все понятно, но я хочу вернуть body через return.

Comment: да и вернет то undefined.